# Why did my React App change the size of my component?

Tags: reactjs

This is the strangest problem I've come across. I finished the latest draft of a very simple app, and deployed it to Heroku. Was working fine. When I clicked on it today the size of my component changed to be much larger than it was previously.

Nothing I have done seems to work in resizing the components. Here is the app:

https://evening-falls-56985.herokuapp.com/

As you can see the area under the navbar is larger than the screen. This wasn't the case when I deployed it.

Here is the relevant code from my container component:

```
var React = require("react");
var Navbar = require("./Navbar");
var Projects = require("./Projects");
var AboutMe = require("./About");
var Contact = require("./Contact");
var Default = require("./Default");
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');


var componentToRender = <Default key = {'default'} />;

var Container = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            page: 'Default',
        };
    },



    componentWillUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState) {


        if(nextState.page == 'Default') { 
            componentToRender = <Default key = {nextState.page} />;
            }

        if (nextState.page == 'Projects') {
            componentToRender =  <Projects key = {nextState.page} />; 

        }

        if (nextState.page == 'Contact') {
            componentToRender = <Contact key = {nextState.page} />;
        }

        if (nextState.page == 'About') {
            componentToRender =   <AboutMe key = {nextState.page} />;
        }


    },

    pageSelected: function(newpage){
        this.setState({page:newpage});

    }, 


    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
             <Navbar pageSelected = {this.pageSelected} />
             <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
          transitionName="example" 
          transitionAppear={true} 
          transitionAppearTimeout={500}
          transitionEnterTimeout={500} 
          transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>

               {componentToRender} 

             </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>

            );
    }

});


module.exports = Container;
```

Comment: Try removing the background image and see what happen. I believe that the image being loading is too wide, the dynamic rendering of left/padding is being calculated based on the image's width. For example, the "My Profile" page doesn't have this problem and, does not have the image over the background.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rendered result `<div class>`, you might miss the CSS class for the div container. (Sometimes we may forget to use `className` as `class` in ReactJS, typo, or import the CSS by the wrong ways.)

[image: missed CSS class for div]
Or you just need to use style (max-width or width) to limit the img's width.